# Issue saving emails directly from Outlook 2010 to SharePoint 2010 mapped drive when using G Suite Sync for Microsoft Outlook

Tags: g-suite, outlook-2010, sharepoint-2010, microsoft

Problem as described above.

Outlook returns 'The operation failed. The messaging interfaces have returned an unknown error. If the problem persists, restart Outlook.'

Happens when User tries to save email directly from Outlook 2010 to SharePoint 2010 mapped drive with G Suite Sync for Microsoft Outlook.

I have tried all the common troubleshooting steps.
Repair MS Office, repair PST, recreate profile, disable Exchange in Outlook, etc.

It will work in Safe Mode but that is not a permanent fix.

Workaround is to save to local machine and then upload to network share.
However, user does this at high volume so the extra steps are cumbersome.

Appreciate any help or suggestions. There is not a lot of info out there in regards to this.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was path length being greater than 255 characters.